Well-Definedness of a Specific Integral Operator
I'm currently working through a problem in abstract harmonic analysis, and came across this remark that I can't verify.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $H<G$ be a closed subgroup, with $dx$ Haar measure on $G$, $d\xi$ the Haar measure on $H$.  Define $P: C_c(G) \longrightarrow C_c(G/H)$ by: $$Pf(xH) := \int_{H} f(x\xi) \: d\xi.$$ ... It's clear that $Pf$ is continuous.

I am having trouble showing that $Pf$ is actually continuous.  It suffices to prove that if $x_iH \longrightarrow xH$ in $G/H$, then $g_i \longrightarrow g$ in the inductive limit topology on $C_c(H)$ where $g_i(\xi) := f(x_i\xi)$ and $g(\xi) := f(x\xi)$.
Now, by uniform continuity of $f$, we have for $\epsilon >0$ a neighborhood $V$ of $e \in G$ such that $$|g_i(\xi)-g(\xi)|= |f(x_i\xi)-f(x\xi)| < \epsilon$$ whenever $\xi^{-1}x^{-1}_ix\xi \in V \iff x^{-1}_ix \in \xi V \xi^{-1} \implies x^{-1}_ix \in HVH$.  However, the last implication doesn't reverse, so it doesn't seem to imply that $x^{-1}_ix \in HVH \implies x_i^{-1}x \in \xi V \xi^{-1}$.
I also don't see how you you could use something like the $L^p$ continuity of left translation since the integral is over $H$ and $x \in G$, so it doesn't need to be in $H$..

The problem with your approach is that $g_i\to g$ need not be true, because $x_iH$ being close to $xH$ does not imply that $x_i$ is close to $x$! To fix this we choose another representative of the coset:
Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $e\in G$ such that $|f(y)-f(z)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $yz^{-1}\in V$. Denote by $q:G\to G/H$ the quotient map. Let $x_0,x\in G$ be such that $x\in q(Vx_0)$, so $x=vx_0h$ with $v\in V,h\in H$. Since $Pf(xH)$ does not depend on the choice of coset representative (by left invariance of the Haar measure), we can replace $x$ by $xh$ so that we may assume $h=1$. Then $x\xi(x_0\xi)^{-1}=xx_0^{-1}=v\in V$, so $$|f(x\xi)-f(x_0\xi)|<\varepsilon.$$
Now this together with $f$ having compact support will imply that $Pf$ is continuous (though a small extra argument is needed here as we have to consider sets of the form $(x\operatorname{supp} f)\cap H$).
